# Arithmetic Arranger TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to build a function that returns an arithmetic arrangement.
Input: `arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])`
Output:

```
   32      3801      45      123
+ 698    -    2    + 43    +  49
-----    ------    ----    -----
```

If the other argument is `True`, `arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"], True)`:
Output:

```
  32         1      9999      523
+  8    - 3801    + 9999    -  49
----    ------    ------    -----
  40     -3800     19998      474
```

I made this one:

```
def arithmetic_arranger(problems, show = True):
  #["1 + 3", "1 - a", "1 * 4"]
  arranged_problems = []
  #too many problems supplied
  if len(problems)>5:
    return "Error: Too many problems."
  for i, ele in enumerate(problems):
    sub = ele.split()
    num1 = sub[0]
    oper = sub[1]
    num2 = sub[2]
    #appropriate operators "+","-"
    if sub[1] not  in "-+":
      return "Error: Operator must be '+' or '-'."
    #only contain digits
    if sub[0].isdigit() and sub[2].isdigit() is False:
        return "Error: Numbers must only contain digits."
    #max 4 digits
    if len(sub[0])>4 or len(sub[2])>4:
      return "Error: Numbers cannot be more than four digits."
      
    ray = "-"

    maxlen_line = max(len(num1), len(num2))
    ach = maxlen_line + 2

    line_num1 = f"{num1:>{ach}}"
    line_num2 = oper + f"{num2:>{ach-1}}"
    line_rays = ray*ach
    
    try:
      arranged_problems[0] += (" "*4) + line_num1
    except IndexError:
      arranged_problems.append(line_num1)
    try:
      arranged_problems[1] += (" "*4) + line_rays
    except IndexError:
      arranged_problems.append(line_rays)
    try:
      arranged_problems[2] += (" "*4) + line_num2
    except IndexError:
      arranged_problems.append(line_num2)
    answ = 0 
    if oper == "+":
      answ = int(num1) + int(num2)
    else:
      answ = int(num1) - int(num2)
    
    line_answ = f"{str(answ):>{ach}}"
    try:
      arranged_problems[3] += (" "*4) + line_answ
    except IndexError:
      arranged_problems.append(line_answ)
    if show == True:
      arranged_problems = f"{arranged_problems[0]}\n{arranged_problems[1]}\n{arranged_problems[2]}\n{arranged_problems[3]}"
    else:
      arranged_problems = f"{arranged_problems[0]}\n{arranged_problems[1]}\n{arranged_problems[2]}"
      
    
  return arranged_problems
```

And this my result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/boilerplate-arithmetic-formatter/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"]))
  File "/home/runner/boilerplate-arithmetic-formatter/arithmetic_arranger.py", line 32, in arithmetic_arranger
    arranged_problems[0] += (" "*4) + line_num1
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I do not understand why because in `arranged_problems[0]` each argument is a `str`.

Thanks!

Comment: but `line_num1` is a string and `(" "*4)` too. I didn't understand.

Comment: I still don't understand: `print(type(line_num1)) =<class 'str'>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get to line 54-57:

```
    if show == True:
      arranged_problems = f"{arranged_problems[0]}\n{arranged_problems[1]}\n{arranged_problems[2]}\n{arranged_problems[3]}"
    else:
      arranged_problems = f"{arranged_problems[0]}\n{arranged_problems[1]}\n{arranged_problems[2]}"
```

You are assigning arranged_problems as a string. It is no longer a list after this. During the next loop iteration, you then get to line 32:

```
arranged_problems[0] += (" "*4) + line_num1
```

which tries to reassign a value in the string's character array. As strings are immutable, this throws that error. The (" "*4) + line_num1 section can evaluate to a string fine, but once arranged_problems is a string you can't assign into it.

To fix this, you need to change the assignment at lines 54-57 so that you aren't overwriting arranged_problems with a string.